# Create storyboard and doubleanimation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I am making the game [SizzlingHot](http://kazinoigri.com/267/sizzling-hot/) on WPF. I have a canvas in which to load the falling images of fruits. When I click on the startButton it should create a storyboard with a doubleAnimation for the falling fruit. I have the following code in the method:

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

Cherry cherry = new Cherry(); // I get the image from this class
// GameCanvas.Children.Add(cherry.FruitImage); // idk if this should be here and its invalid because the parameter in the parantheses shoud be UI element it does not allow BitmapImage                    

DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(100, 500, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
myDoubleAnimation.From = -150;
myDoubleAnimation.To = 500;            

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation, cherry.FruitImage); 
Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();                    

myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
GameCanvas.Resources.Add(myStoryboard,cherry.FruitImage);

myStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
```

When I run this, on the last line, it gives me a

> InvalidOperationException - Operation is not valid due to the current stage of the object.

I don't understand what seems to be the problem here when I debug it I can see that the image is found.

Comment: Where exactly do you add the element to the canvas? You should animate the containing `Image` and not the `BitmapImage` source.

Comment: I add it with Canvas.Children.Add(myImage) and it is not the source it is my image, but an error pops out Unable to convert Bitmap to System.Windows.UIElement. Isn't this the right method for adding stuff to canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You can only add `UIElement` to a `Canvas`, Adding a `BitmapImage` directly to a `Canvas` will not work.

One option could be to add a dynamic `Image` and set the `Source` to your `FruitImage` then you can animate/position the `Image` on your `GameCanvas`

Example:

```
Cherry cherry = new Cherry();

// Create host for BitmapImage
Image imageHost = new Image { Source = cherry.FruitImage };
GameCanvas.Children.Add(imageHost);

// Animate Image
imageHost.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, new DoubleAnimation(-150, 500, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))));
```

Comment: @DimitarAndreev please mark an answer as correct if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this on your image, if you haven't already:

```
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
cherryImage.Source = image;
```

Comment: Ok the InvalidOperationException doesn't show up but still nothing appears on screen.

Comment: Please note that this could be written a lot shorter: `cherryImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));`. There is no need for BeginInit/EndInit when you just want to create a BitmapImage from an Uri.

Answer (score 0):

In case `cherry.FruitImage` is an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx), you could simply animate it like this:

```
cherry.FruitImage.BeginAnimation(
    Canvas.TopProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation(-150, 500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
```

No need for a Storyboard.